# Query MongoDB to implement typheahead in ui

Tags: mongodb, typeahead

I am trying to query my MongoDB to find all the matching name fields in the documents of my collection from the typeahead of my angular ui, I have to display the contents of the matched documents in table format, I referred few docs and wrote this API, when  I try to test in Advanced REST client , it displays connection timed out, can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong?
My API code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var enterprise = mongoose.model('enterprise');

    var search = function(req, res){
    function searchEnterprise(){

        var name = req.params.name;
        enterprise.find({"name": '/^'+ name + '$/i'},function(err, data){
            if (err){
                console.log('err',err);
            } else {
                res.json(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
    }
    module.exports = {
        searchEnterprise : search
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need nested function  `searchEnterprise()`. just use it

```
var search = function(req, res){
    var name = req.params.name;

    // can also use $regex like bellow line
    //enterprise.find({'name': {$options:'i', $regex: name }}, or
    // enterprise.find({"name": '/'+ name + '/i'}

    enterprise.find({'name': {$options:'i', $regex: name }},function(err, data){
        if (err){
            console.log('err',err);
            return res.status(400).send({msg: "error"});
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            return res.json(data); 
            // or
            //return res.status(200).send(data);
        }
   });
};

module.exports = {
     searchEnterprise : search
};
```

Comment: empty array means not found any data with matched condition